# How did the WallstreetBet community know that Game Stop was shorted so heavily?

Tags: stocks

What I understand from the whole Game Stop soaring stock prices event is that Game Stop stocks were in essence shorted too heavily, there were more stocks borrowed/shorted than in existence. This enabled people from the WallstreetBet community and others to inflate the stock price massively by buying it. What I want to know is how/where the WallstreetBet community got the information that it was shorted so/too heavily. Were it just statements from big investors that they shorted heavily on Game Stop stocks? Or did/could they get information from other sources too about how much the stock was shorted?

Comment: Someone on Quantitative Finance provided a thorough answer: [Without Bloomberg, how can retail investors know how many shares have been shorted daily?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/60794/without-bloomberg-how-can-retail-investors-know-how-many-shares-have-been-short).

Answer (score 6):

> Or did/could they get information from other sources too about how much the stock was shorted?

[The number of shorted shares for a given company is publicly known](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/36701/2183). E.g. see https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GME/history?p=GME  ([mirror](https://archive.vn/oLaKw)).